# Need CSS pattern for the selenium in python to locate the element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

This is the HTML syntax but I want to locate the element using value "ADD QUERY" using find_element_by_css_selector.

Image of HTML:
[image: Image HTML]

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.global-button-primary.telemetry-button")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'global-button-primary') and contains(@class, 'telemetry-button')][contains(., 'ADD QUERY')]")
  ```

Ideally, to locate the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.global-button-primary.telemetry-button")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'global-button-primary') and contains(@class, 'telemetry-button')][contains(., 'ADD QUERY')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```